# Can you successfully migrate ArcGIS 10.0 mxd to 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, installation, mxd

I have upgraded from 10.0 to ArcGIS 10.1.  I am trying to open an 10.0 mxd file in 10.1 and it appears to have lost any additions I had made to the table plus its' x and y coordinates.  Can you successfully migrate ArcGIS 10.0 mxd to 10.1?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what got lost between the versions? I have also migrated to 10.1 recently, but haven't had any issues yet.

Comment: I'm unclear too.  Has your shapefile/feature class lost recent edits? There are no special steps to migrate a project, you just open it in ArcMap 10.1.  That doesn't mean you can't have problems, the ESRI Forums have indicated there can be many.  The usual suggestions are to use Save As to update the mxd to the newest version, update any file geodatabases to the newest as well. Sometimes during updates one has to try the boilerplate appoach of renaming of the ESRI application data folder to "fix" problem templates or registry entries.  You lose your customizations doing the latter.

Comment: You should be able to open a 10.0 mxd in 10.1 without any issues. You will not be able to open a 10.1 mxd in 10.0 though. Do you have the service pack and patches installed? I have lost data as you have described in both versions, but that was always due to the network connection dropping in the middle of an edit session, and not from simply opening a 10.0 mxd in 10.1.

Comment: This is a long shot, but is it possible you're experiencing one of these issues? http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41119?WT.mc_id=EmailCampaign16217

Comment: also, for troubleshooting, it'd be helpful to know if you tried opening these datasets in ArcCatalog or a new map document and experienced the same missing data

Answer (score 2):

There should be no special steps. Although, you should keep in mind that if other people are working with the same mxd and do not have 10.1 they will not be able to open it. In that case, you should "save a copy as..." a 10.0 document.